# Grid effect as in background-clip: text

Tags: css

How to make such a gradient effect? The entire page has a gradient underneath, the container is black, and individual grids have a fragment of the gradient underneath as the background. The effect should be like `background-clip: text;` only block element instead of text.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of pseudo element and clip-path can do this:

```css
.grid {
  display:grid;
  gap:20px;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  position:relative; /* relative here */
  z-index:0;
}
.grid div {
  aspect-ratio:1;
  clip-path:inset(0); /* clip the pseudo element to the child dimension*/
}
.grid div:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  inset:0;
  z-index:-1;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg,red,blue); /* your gradient */
}

body {
 background:#000
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```